# CSS: Change the height of previous div in code

Tags: html, css, hover, transition

This is a little complicated to explain as a non-native speaker, so here is the current state: 
http://test.moritzfriedrich.com

So I have a container filling almost the whole page. It is devided in two halfs.
Each of them has three divs filled with content. I want them two grow bigger if you click/hover on them. For the action on hover i use css3-transitions and change the height of the divs. But my problem is they only grow downwards. 
Here's the code:

CSS:

```
html, body {
  background: url(/images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#wrapper {
  margin: 1% auto;
  overflow: hidden !important;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  min-height: 90%;
  height:auto !important;
  height:90%;
}
/* Left Side ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */
 #top_left {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  height: 15%;
}
#left {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 75%;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
#description_left {
  background: #111;
  height: 50%;
}
#description_left:hover {
  height: 40%;
}
#description_left:hover ~ #slider_left {
  height: 25%;
}
#description_left:hover ~ #contact_left {
  height: 10%;
}
#slider_left {
  background: #222;
  height: 40%;
}
#slider_left:hover {
  height: 40%;
}
#slider_left:hover ~ #description_left {
  height: 10%;
}
#slider_left:hover ~ #contact_left {
  height: 25%;
}
#contact_left {
  background: #333;
  height: 10%;
}
#contact_left:hover {
  height: 40%;
}
#contact_left:hover ~ #description_left {
  height: 25%;
}
#contact_left:hover ~ #slider_left {
  height: 10%;
}
/* Right Side ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */
 ...
```

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="top_left"></div>
    <div id="top_right"></div>
    <div id="left">
      <div id="description_left"></div>
      <div id="slider_left"></div>
      <div id="contact_left"></div>
      <div style="clear: both"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
      <div id="description_right"></div>
      <div id="slider_right"></div>
      <div id="contact_right"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The adjacent sibling connector makes the other divs change their style aswell, but as I said they only grow/shrink towards the bottom when I want them to grow equally.

Is there a way to do this without JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add a margin percentage on top of the  and reduce the margin by the same percentage by which you grow the div on hover. That will make sure your div sticks to the bottom. Example:

```
#some-div{
  height:30%;
  margin-top: 10%; /*Now my effective height for performing hover: 40%
  /*some other properties*/
  transition: all .2s;
}

#some-div:hover{
  height:40%; /*height grows*/
  margin-top: 0%; /*Margin shrinks allowing the div to grow on top only*/
}
```

This will work..
:)